# Iterating over *ngFor with a static array of objects constantly updates the DOM

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple component which iterates over a static array of objects and displays the content. When this component is added into the larger application, the content is displayed correctly but I am unable to register any click events on it. When I inspect the element in chrome using `right click -> Inspect` I am greeted with the body tag and it doesn't drill down to the individual element as expected.

By navigating manually, inspecting the element idicates that the component is constantly being updated by the DOM (div tag flashes). By my understanding there shouldn't be any change detected since it is a static array.

Changing the object array to a simple string array `['a', 'b', 'c']` behaves as expected and the DOM isn't being updated.

Adding additional elements the template outside of the ngFor are unaffected and aren't being constantly updated.

I am using v2.4.1

**Simplified Component**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-ngfor-test',
 templateUrl: './ngfor-test.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./ngfor-test.component.css']
})
export class NgforTestComponent {
 
 get items() {
  return [
   {
    'label': 'a',
    'value': 'first'
   },
   {
    'label': 'b',
    'value': 'second'
   },
   {
    'label': 'c',
    'value': 'third'
   }
  ];
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

**Template**

```html
<div class="item-container" *ngFor="let item of items">
 <label>{{ item.label | uppercase }}</label>
 <span>{{ item.value }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @seidme mentioned the getter is called every time change detection runs, which can be quite often.

```
get items() {
    return [
        {
            'label': 'a',
            'value': 'first'
        },
        {
            'label': 'b',
            'value': 'second'
        },
        {
            'label': 'c',
            'value': 'third'
        }
    ];
}
```

returns a new object instance every time it is called, which causes `ngFor` to re-render the list.

If you change it to

```
items = [
        {
            'label': 'a',
            'value': 'first'
        },
        {
            'label': 'b',
            'value': 'second'
        },
        {
            'label': 'c',
            'value': 'third'
        }
    ];

get items() {
  return this.items;
}
```

it will stop re-rendering, because Angular recognizes it got the same object instance and nothing has changed and nothing needs to be updated or re-rendered.

Comment: Thanks. This helps to understand why an object array behaves differently to a string array. I'm using a getter because I want the contents to be displayed dynamically based off a repsonse I get from a server.

Comment: You still can update `this.items` when the response from the server arrives, but this way it's only modified (and re-rendered) when it actually was changed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I achieved dynamic values by utilising a setter

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to the `*ngFor` directive.  `get` syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up (every time Angular runs change detection), which in your case always returns a new array object (reference changes), forcing the Angular to re-render the list.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it could be that, but this doesn't explain why it works as expected when the object array is replaced with a string array

Comment: I am wondering it works for string array because angular goes through all the strings internally and  repaints the dom only if something has changed, even though array object is a new one?